# Accessing Oracle packages with C# MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Oracle package that gives a list of facilities based on user ID. It is used to determine access. We have several projects that use this package already but they are all VB and WebForms - we are moving over to C# and MVC and this is the first project like that utilizing this package.

When attempting to run a query in the package, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException: The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure.`

Procedure spec (I do not have access to the body and this part cannot be edited as it is used extensively in other applications):

```
Procedure GetFacilitiesByUser
(
  p_EmpNo   IN  int,
  cur_OUT   out sys_refcursor
);
```

And my C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle;

namespace MvcApplication1.DataAccess
{
    public class InpatientSecurity
    {
        public List<string> GetHospitals(int EmployeeNumber)
        {
            var response = new List<string>() { };
            object[] _params = { EmployeeNumber };
            IDataReader dr = ExecuteQuery(
                "connection string",
                "datawarehouse.Access.GetFacilitiesByUser",
                _params
            );
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                response.Add("test");
            }
            return response;
        }

        private IDataReader ExecuteQuery(string provider, string procedure, params object[] args)
        {
            var _db = new OracleDatabase(provider);
            object[] objArr = new object[args.Length];
            args.CopyTo(objArr, 0);
            if (args.Length > 1)
            {
                objArr[objArr.Length - 1] = System.DBNull.Value;
            }
            IDataReader reader = _db.ExecuteReader(procedure, objArr); /* Exception thrown here */
            _db = null;
            return reader;
        }
    }
}
```

I did not write the original VB code used to access this procedure, this is just a

Comment: Calling package shouldn't be different with C#, VB, MVC or Win forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I figured it out shortly after posting. The objArr array needs to be of length 2, I guess to take into account the ref cursor? Changing the following line in ExecuteQuery() fixed the issue.

Change this:

```
object[] objArr = new object[args.Length];
```

To this:

```
object[] objArr = new object[args.Length + 1];
```